# How to read in integers (X and Y points) from a file and plot a least regression line in Java? Error

Tags: java

So, Assuming I'm to read from a .txt file a set of points and plot a least square regression line on top of the points.  (i'm not that familiar with stats either)

> My program would plot the points using text (for example, with "X"s representing the points, "-"s the regression line segments,
>   and " * "s where a line segment and a point are located at the same spot)

These are the points to be read from the file (first integer x and second y). x-coordinates are in the range [0, 40] and the y-coordinates in the range [1, 20].

```
20 10
0  1
40 20
13 17
13 12
10 ?
the x coordinates represent time
15 0
10 20
```

`There are some invalid points in this text but the program would eventually ignore it but do not stop reading the file.`

Here's what i've come up with, but still gives error of ArrayIndexBound:2

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        processValuesFromFile("points.txt");

    }

    public static void processValuesFromFile(String filename){
        BufferedReader inputFile;
        String line;
        int[][] points;

        try{
            inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            line = inputFile.readLine();

            while(line!= null){
                points = readPoints(inputFile,line);
                printPoints(points);
                //
                line = inputFile.readLine();
            }
            inputFile.close();



        }catch (IOException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] readPoints(BufferedReader inputFile, String line) throws IOException{
        String[] split;
        String inputLine;
        int[][] points;
        int pointSize = 9;

        points = new int[pointSize][pointSize];
        for(int row=0; row<pointSize;row++){
            inputLine = inputFile.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputFile);
            split = inputLine.split("\\s+");

            for(int col =0; col <pointSize;col++){
                points[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(split[col]);
            }

        }
        return points;

    }

    public static void printPoints(int[][] points) {
        for (int row=0; row < points.length; row++) {
            for (int col=0; col < points[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(points[row][col] +"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clearly some homework question. Please spending some time trying things out and then you can request help with specific things you run into.

Comment: specific thing? i'm just asking on how to read values in 2d arrays? @codesalsa

Comment: How about trying to be a bit "more" specific -- Do you know how to read text from a text file? Do you know how to do this line by line? Do you know how to split the two bits of information found on that line? Do you know how to parse a String into an int? Please "divide and conquer", try to solve each small step, and then come back with your *most* specific question after trying to solve that which you ***are*** able to solve.

Comment: Yes, I know how to read texts from files, split them with several delimiters and parse them. I'm stuck on how to read this text as each value represents a int for either X or Y. Splitting them into arrays would be different from just splitting any texts. I'm still doing my research on how to split the so as one row represents a value for X and Y. Do you have an idea? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: For one, you're not using the BufferedReader correctly. You read until the line read in from the BufferedReader is null, not the BufferedReader itself.

Comment: my bad! it was an editing error I was switching the variables. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I know one of my problems is hanging around at the code `int pointSize =9` that's where the problem of giving it a size comes from @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Don't use a 2D array if you don't know the size. Create a Point class (or use `java.awt.Point`), and create and fill an `ArrayList<Point>`. This flexible collection was built for just this sort of situation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'd apply that.@HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 2):

It's better to create a class that represent the points.

```
class Point{

int x;
int y;

}
```

and then you create an array or a collection of points

```
Point[] points = new Point[10];
```

or

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

Comment: I'll try that. i'm currently creating two methods. One to process the file and the other to read from it and maybe another to check for invalid values and the next to plot.